# JavaScript Failed to fetch in Windows Forms BlazorWebView

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, blazor-webassembly

Using Visual Studio Community 2022 and .NET6, created a Blazor WebAssembly project which included some JavaScript that used `fetch` to call an API. This works fine.

I then moved most of the code into a Razor class library (RCL) in order to be able to use it from my Blazor WebAssembly or from a Windows Forms BlazorWebView. The Blazor WebAssembly using the RCL works fine. But the Windows Forms BlazorWebView using the RCL fails as soon as the JavaScript uses `fetch` to call the API.

To simplify matters, I have removed the RCL from the equation and started over with a simple Windows Forms app using BlazorWebView. I used [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/windows-forms?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-6.0) and reproduced the problem. If I can find a solution to this, then hopefully I can use it for the RCL approach as well.

## Here is what I added to the tutorial above to reproduce the problem:

I added some JavaScript (Counter.js) to the wwwroot folder of the project:

```
window.CounterJSFunctions = {
    callFetch: async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://12.34.56.78:5001/api/values');
        return await response.text();
    }
};
```

I referenced the JavaScript from the index.html in the wwwroot folder of the project:

```
<script type="module" src="Counter.js"></script>
```

I modified the Razor component (Counter.razor) to call the API directly (which works) and then by means of the JavaScript (which fails):

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject HttpClient Http
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private string currentCount = "";

    private async void IncrementCount()
    {
        // this works:
        //currentCount += await Http.GetStringAsync("http://12.34.56.78:5001/api/values");
        // this fails:
        currentCount += await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("CounterJSFunctions.callFetch");
    }
}
```

The exception I get says:

```
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: 'Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.callFetch (https://0.0.0.0/Counter.js:4:32)
    at https://0.0.0.0/_framework/blazor.webview.js:1:3332
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://0.0.0.0/_framework/blazor.webview.js:1:3306)
    at https://0.0.0.0/_framework/blazor.webview.js:1:40711
    at EventTarget.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:7:62)
    at EmbeddedBrowserWebView.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:37376)'
```

The source is `System.Private.CoreLib` and there is no inner exception.

I made sure CORS is enabled on the API, and tried a different public API as well. I was expecting the JavaScript to behave the same as in the browser (using WebAssembly). Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Fiddler reveals that no request is sent. If I call a public API on HTTPS, it works. If I call a public API on HTTP, it fails. I need to call the API on HTTP, so how can I do this?

Comment: Try to run a local proxy like Fiddler to see exactly what http request is being made and what response is returned.